# SystemInfo Batch File Issues

Tags: windows

I am trying to get the systeminfo in to a csv file. I have written following batch file:

```
@echo off
systeminfo /fo csv > D:\mySystemInfo.csv
```

The batch file:

1. creates an output file by the name of "mySystemInfo.csv"

But the file is completely blank and the command prompt is also blank. Only the cursor keeps blinking.

I am using windows 7

Comment: works for me... what if you only run systeminfo /fo csv from the commandprompt?

Comment: it shows the output in command prompt. But I want to extract the information in a csv / xls / xlsx file so that information can be transferred in to another file.

Comment: Ok, now run systeminfo /fo csv > info.csv. The info.csv file should be in your current folder. In you batch file try to put the csv in a folder instead if  the root of D:\  (d:\log\info.csv for example)

Answer (score 0):

You should write path directly after command redirection operators like **>**

```
@echo off
systeminfo /fo csv>D:\mySystemInfo.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to have the /fo csv just use

```
systeminfo >>D:\MySystemInfo.csv
```

Itll take the output of the command "systeminfo" and place into the file MySystemInfo.csv on the D drive [assuming that you have a D:\ drive to store it in.]

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate having same issues how should i solve it. ?